# How to browse directory and save path as a variable in a file using tcl/tk

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Is there an example to browse and locate directory and save that as a variable in file.

I found an example but can't get it to work, however I'm not sure if heading in the correct direction or if there is a better way to do the above.

Help/advice is appreciated.

```
set basedir {C:/}

set dir [tk_chooseDirectory \
        -initialdir $basedir -title "Choose a directory"]
if {$dir eq ""} {
   label .l -text "No directory selected"
} else {
   label .l -text "Selected $dir"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's approximately how you do it. If you're worried about the label not becoming visible, you just need to get it "managed" first, like

```
grid [label .l -text "Selected $dir"]
```

or, after the `if` structure

```
grid .l
```

Or, if the label is already managed but the text doesn't show up, you set the text:

```
.l configure -text "Selected $dir"
```

To save the directory path in a file, you need to open the file and write to it in some way, e.g.

```
set f [open file.txt w]
puts $f $dir
close $f
```

If something else is the problem, you will have to tell us what it is before we can help you.

Documentation: [close](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/close.htm), [grid](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/grid.htm), [label](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/label.htm), [open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

Comment: Thanks Peter, yes it was basically not displaying the label. I've got just under a 3 days of experience with Tk widgets, still trying to digest it all.